# Visual Studio Properties Web tab Start Action Specific Page: how is this value published to the server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

In an ASP.NET web project in Visual Studio, on the Properties page, Web tab, in the Start Actions section, you can specify a specific page, e.g. foo.aspx.

How is this information conveyed from the dev PC up to the IIS server? Is it baked into the DLL? Or does `web.config` get updated with it?

Or is this value only valid during development?

Comment: I think it is just - Start IISExpress, prepare the site, request the specific page.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I'll edit my question in case it wasn't clear. There's a development PC and a separate server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little manip on the IIS.
First, open IIS Manager, select your website and double click on Default Document icon. 
On the opened screen, on the right of the screen click the Add button to add your default page, like foo.aspx.
Select the foo.aspx and move it to the top of the list using up/down buttons on the right of the screen.

[image: Select your website and double click to Default Document]

[image: Add a new default document]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply with screen-shots. If I understand you correctly, the local setting on the development machine has no impact on the server, is that right?

Comment: You'e welcome. Your project settings no but your web.config yes. If you set a value in your web.config file, IIS will recognise this value.